# NetBeans does not recognise <<<_END

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm trying to learn PHP using NetBeans although I've come up against a problem with the interpreter and I can't tell how to fix it.

It's to do with the notation <<<_END. It should, from what I'm learning wrap everything into a variable until it's ended with _END

However, if I plug in the following example:

```
<?php
        echo <<<_END 
        <html><head><title>PHP form upload</title></head><body><form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
        <input type='submit' value='Upload'/>
        </form>

        _END

        if ($_FILES)
        {
            $name = $_FILES ['filename']['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES ['filename'][tmp_none], $name);
            echo "Uploaded image '$name' <br/> <img src='$name'/>";

        }
        echo "</body></html>";
        ?>
```

I get the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in script.php on line 13, where line 13 is the code that says 'echo <<<_END'.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be no space/tab/indentation before ending `_END` like this:

```
       echo <<<_END 
        <html><head><title>PHP form upload</title></head><body><form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
        <input type='submit' value='Upload'/>
        </form>
_END;
```

> Don't forget that it is not allowed to
>   indent the closing tag if you do so
>   you will get a parsing error.

http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Missing semicolon after `_END`
2. You can't have any indentation before `_END`

Comment: Your answer works in my case for netbeans IDE. You can not have indentation between heredoc string syntax <<<_END and _END.